# Can I view rules for Crayon Rail games online?

Tags: crayon-rail-games

Where can I find the rules to a given crayon rail game online?  I have tried looking on a game page (i.e. [EuroRails](http://mayfairgames.com/game.php?id=110&stock=MFG4507&name=EuroRails)), but there is no link to the rules there.  I did manage to find a [link to the Empire Express rules](http://mayfairgames.com/mfg-shop3/rules/MFG4500-Overview-V1_0.pdf), but I'd like links to the other rail games, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't see a complete rulebook for EuroRails, the [BoardgameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/157/eurorails) page does contain a number of reference sheets. I'd start with the BGG page for each game you're interested in and go from there.